# Caching XAP files using local storage

Tags: silverlight, mef, local-storage

I'm trying to cache Silverlight XAP files using modern browsers' localStorage - not Silverlight Isolated Storage - to save download time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

XAP files are automatically cached by the browser and (assuming you don't clear the cache) not downloaded again when you next run the application.

You can improve download speed by checking the "Reduce XAP size by using application library caching" option in the project settings and making sure that any third party assemblies you use have extmap files. This will create a separate XAP file for each project in your solution and put the 3<sup>rd</sup> party assemblies into zip files shared by all XAP files.

This should a) reduce the size of each XAP file your application needs and b) only require updated assemblies and/or projects to be downloaded next time your application runs.

Comment: **Thank you**, I am already know that browser cache xap files, I want to control this process by using localstorage, I will try to decode xap files into base64 and download it using javascript and then access it throw javascript from silverlight

Comment: @MrBassam - I don't think this will save download time.

Comment: **Agree**, Base64 adds about 33% more to file size, But it will be downloaded once